# BG95 reboot by itself

Tags: embedded-linux, iot, quectel

I am building IOT device using a LTE modem form Quectel, the BG95, together with NXP imx6, running Linux. The sim card I am using has the technology of eMTC.

Normally the device is working fine, the issue I am having now, is that the device lost LTE communication randomly (typically after 3-6 days uptime).

My setup

- I have disabled echo mode in the BG95 at my init procedure.
- I have a periodical call to send AT command "AT+CREG?" toward BG95, and read the response.

What I am seeing from the debugging is following:

- My periodical at command "AT+CREG" toward BG95 is not responding.
- Linux kernel reports ttyUSB towards BG95 is disconnected.
- 3-4 seconds, the kernel reports ttyUSB toward BG95 is connected again.
- My periodical AT command "AT+CREG" toward BG95 is returning ERROR.
- I see from the serial reading from the BG95 has "APP RDY".
- I see from the serial reading from the BG95 has echo mode enabled.

Form what I am seeing, I am assuming that the BG95 is somehow "rebooted".

Is there any reason why the BG95 will reboot itself? Or how to confirm this?

I checked the datasheet of BG95, but I cannot find a AT command or other way to check the boot reason.

Do you have other suggestion on how to debug this further? Or similar experience with BG95?

Thanks